# How do I make it so that every Chapter starts at an odd-numbered page, preceded by a blank page?

Tags: numbering, chapters, books, parts, blank-page

I recently began to work in Latex to make a book. This book is composed by two books of the same author, so its made of two parts. It has been a big challenge, and many issues have arisen.
How do I make it so that every Chapter starts at an odd-numbered page, preceded by a blank page?
I can't find some codes combination that allow me to this:

| :even | :odd: |
| --- | --- |
| BlankPage | StartChapter1 |
| CorpusChapter1 | EndChapter1 |
| BlankPage | StartChapter2 |

and

| even | odd |
| --- | --- |
| BlankPage | StartChapter1 |
| EndChapter1 | BlankPage |
| BlankPage | StartChapter2 |

The structure of the text I actually used:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[width=3.93in, height=6.49in, top=1.0in, papersize={5.5in,8.2in}]{geometry}
\makeatletter\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}\makeatother%
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage [utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\part{%
  \if@openright
    \cleardoublepage
  \else
    \clearpage
  \fi
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \if@twocolumn
    \onecolumn
    \@tempswatrue
  \else
    \@tempswafalse
  \fi
  \null\vfil
  \secdef\@part\@spart}
\makeatother
%%%%%% CENTERED CHAPTER%%%%%%%
\usepackage{sectsty}
\chapterfont{\Large \centering}
\sectionfont{\normalsize \centering}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\fancyhf{}
\lfoot[\thepage]{}
\rfoot[]{\thepage}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{% % <-- this is new
  \fancyhf{} 
  \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage} % same placement as with page style "fancy"
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}}
  \usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}
\include{cover} 
\restoregeometry
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\frontmatter
\mainmatter
\part{Part1}
\Chapter{A}
\Chapter{B}
\Chapter{C}
\part{Part2}
\Chapter{A}
\Chapter{B}
\Chapter{C}
\end{document}
```

Comment: use \cleartoeven to get to an even page then `\mbox{}\clearpage` to start the chapter. `\cleartoeven` like `\cleardoubleepage` with odd and even reversed

Comment: I can't make \cleartoeven work. I use it before a new chapter but I can't compile.
I want every \Part and \Chapter must begin in an odd numbered page, and be preceded by a blank page.

Answer (score 1):

something like

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[width=3.93in, height=6.49in, top=1.0in, papersize={5.5in,8.2in}]{geometry}
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}
\makeatother%
\usepackage[english]{babel}
% dont use option \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{setspace}
% only for old latex \usepackage [utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{subfiles}
% only for old latex \usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{xpatch}
% alraeady used \usepackage{blindtext}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\part{%
  \if@openright
    \cleardoublepage
  \else
    \clearpage
  \fi
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \if@twocolumn
    \onecolumn
    \@tempswatrue
  \else
    \@tempswafalse
  \fi
  \null\vfil
  \secdef\@part\@spart}

%\cleardoublepage
% with odd/even switched
\def\cleartoeven{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page
     \thispagestyle{plain}\hbox{}\newpage
     \if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}

\makeatother
%%%%%% CENTERED CHAPTER%%%%%%%
\usepackage{sectsty}
\chapterfont{\Large \centering}
\sectionfont{\normalsize \centering}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\fancyhf{}
\lfoot[\thepage]{}
\rfoot[]{\thepage}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{% % <-- this is new
  \fancyhf{} 
  \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage} % same placement as with page style "fancy"
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}}
  \usepackage{etoolbox}

% why new command with C??? you used but did not define
\newcommand\Chapter{\cleartoeven\chapter}
\begin{document}
%\include{cover}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\mbox{}\clearpage
%\restoregeometry
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\frontmatter
\mainmatter
\part{Part1}
\Chapter{A}
text text text text text text text text 
\Chapter{B}
text text text text text text text text 
\Chapter{C}
\part{Part2}
\Chapter{A}
\Chapter{B}
\Chapter{C}
\end{document}
```

[image]